# What is the behavior of an observable within a forEach loop?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

When querying an observable within a `forEach` loop, does a new "instance" of the observable get created on every loop or does the existing observable get overwritten if the next loop query is requested before the previous observable returns a value?

For example, if I have messages to send to my users, I need to query for all their devices and send to all devices. An example of a topic in the topics array that is passed to `createTopics(topics)` would be:

**Single Item in Topics Array**

```
{
    "submission": {
      "id": 52,
      "artistID": 111,
      "title": "Sego Sucks",
      "Artist": {
        "name": "Sego"
      }
    },
    "users": [
      {
        "id": 7,
        "userUID": "ZvOBNBqxbgRYoibSYEwkL9YKtWG2"
      }
    ]
  }
```

My question is, when I run the `forEach` loop, I have an observable in `findUserDevices` that is iterated over several times really quickly, will my observable be "overwritten" by the next loop if it doesn't return a value before the next loop comes about? So far when I run this code, it executes as planned, but I am not sure if this is the best way to handle the observable as my data scales and there are more users per topic especially since `pushToDevices()` is an async function.

```
function createTopics(topics) {
    topics.forEach((topic: any) => {
        const message = {
            notification: {
                title: `New music from ${topic.submission.Artist.name}!`,
                body: `Listen to "${topic.submission.title}" now`
            }
        }

        topic.users.forEach((user) => {
            findUserDevices(user.userUID, message);
        })
    })
}

function findUserDevices(uid: string, message) {
        collectionData(fb.firestore().collection('devices').where('userId', '==', uid)).subscribe((devices: any) => {
            var userDeviceTokens: string[] = devices.map((device: any) => device.token);
            if (userDeviceTokens.length != 0) {
                message['tokens'] = userDeviceTokens;
                pushToDevices(message);
            }
        })
}

async function pushToDevices(message) {
    await admin.messaging().sendMulticast(message).then((response) => {
        console.log('done!')
    })
}
```

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: this will just fire off a bunch of async calls

Comment: "Does a new instance of the observable get created on every loop?", the answer to that question is yes. This means that you can safely instantiate a new Observable for each iteration of your loop like you are doing here, there is nothing wrong with doing that. It will not overwrite the observable in the previous loop.

Comment: Excellent thank you very much for the clarification both of you!